# Android showing a dialog in activity

Tags: java, android, dialog

I created a new class that extends the `DialogFragment` class:

```
public class SaveDataDialog extends DialogFragment {
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        // Get the layout inflater
        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

        // Inflate and set the layout for the dialog
        // Pass null as the parent view because its going in the dialog layout
        builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.save_data_dialog, null))
        // Add action buttons
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.save_data, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Testing positive button", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }).setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        SaveDataDialog.this.getDialog().cancel();
                    }
                });
        return builder.create();
    }

}
```

And somewhere in my main activity (inside of a button onClick), I want to show this dialog. So I tried:

```
SaveDataDialog sdd = new SaveDataDialog();
sdd.getDialog().show();
```

Second line gives a null pointer exception.

How do I show the dialog? That's all I want to do.

Comment: do a `sdd.show()`. You dont have to do `sdd.getDialog().show()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `SaveDataDialog` extends a `DialogFragment`, you can call `sdd.show()` to display the `DialogFragment`.

Comment: I tried: `sdd.show(getFragmentManager(), "SaveDataDialog");` which has the error: `The method show(FragmentManager, String) in the type DialogFragment is not applicable for the arguments (FragmentManager, String)`

Comment: if your are using the support library, then use `getSupportFragmentManager()` instead of the `getFragmentManager()`

Answer (score 1):

try

```
sdd.show();
```

instead of

```
sdd.getDialog().show();
```

since your dialog extends DialogFragment, you don't have to call .getDialog()

More details: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/05/using-dialogfragments.html

Answer (score 1):

Inside your activity use the following code to show your dialog fragment.

```
SaveDataDialog saveDataDialog = new SaveDataDialog();
saveDataDialog.show(getFragmentManager(), SaveDataDialog.class.getName());
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html#show(android.app.FragmentTransaction, java.lang.String)

If your application supports Android versions before 3.0.x. You will need to use the support library and import android.app.v4.DialogFragment.

http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html